# ASP.NET Core Identity - how to use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to find the user using identity.name, but if there are several users with this name, go to error.

I want to return one user using cookies, email is unique, but name not, how to use email?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjBPq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adcrc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSDWz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOFT8.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture of text. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/1115360)

Comment: As @AndrewMorton says. Also, if you ever want to attach pictures to your posts, please add a description, otherwise it's impossible to know what is what.

Comment: Could you please your code snippet so that it can be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have something like this;

1. You have multiple users with the same User.Identity.Name --> How is it possible to have multiple users with the same name?
2. And you want to use email address instead User.Identity.Name --> If you pass email from the view to controller action, you can use something like below;

   var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);